# Cannot access Postgress (in container) from another container in the same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I learned a lot by my self about docker but I still facing one major problem and I need your help, please.

This is my dockercompose:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
 postgres:
  container_name: postgres-tc
  networks:
   - tools-net
  image: postgres
  expose:
   - 5432
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Admin10..
   - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

#service
 teamcity-server:
  ports:
   - '8112:8111'
  volumes:
   - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
   - '/data/teamcity_server/datadir:/data/envdata/tc/datadir'
   - '/opt/teamcity/logs:/data/envdata/tc/logs'
  links:
   - "postgres:postgres"
  logging:
   options:
    max-size: 1g
  container_name: tc-server
  networks:
   - tools-net
  image: jetbrains/teamcity-server

networks:
   tools-net:
    external: true
```

teamcity-serve needs to access postgress on its port to start working.
Both are in the same netwotk created by this command.

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.50.0.0/16 tools-net
```

Here the network inspect after running dockercompose up:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "tools-net",
        "Id": "74708d3d114394032cbeb5f0a2a93893da38ce5dae2a555a451a189b00b52b2e",
        "Created": "2021-07-04T07:04:39.105791768Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.50.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "15a57ccfc229e361e40e940d01b6d6025820fee5ad50db4a61d0c411d4d61750": {
                "Name": "postgres-tc",
                "EndpointID": "8d5b9d192ed90545abe958134b9853d0aecba33cabd56f31a2c9681106ccdf6e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:32:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.50.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "94eaa0ea0524ca4419ba8e300e80687db487e4f46b6623dabcc15d65c60bdde6": {
                "Name": "tc-server",
                "EndpointID": "90825befcc5633c3c59c5ec9d58b188d2862cd65cd2283b5c56ec3ecf5a95fd6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:32:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.50.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Now when I try to access the postgress from teamcity-server I got this error:

[image]

Please guys help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE :**
It seems to be better with your help @Hans.
For now I have another issue :
[image]

My be I have to add a permission into postgress `pg_hba.conf` which I can lot locate within the container.
Can youu help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling Teamcity to connect to a postgres server running on the default localhost address. In Docker terms, that means running *in* in the same container as Teamcity. It isn't.

You need to tell Teamcity to connect to database host `postgres-tc`. That's the network name of the Postgres container on your network.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And how to tell Teamcity to connect to database host postgres-tc?

Comment: In the last screenshot in your post you show the database setup of Teamcity. There's an empty field in it called 'Database host[:port]'. Put `postgres-tc` in it. Since you're running on the default Postgres port, you don't need to put the port number.

Comment: Thanks Hans, please could you see the update?